# What is the type returned by "Load" in FSharp Data's CsvProvider

Tags: f#, f#-data

Consider the following code:

```
  type EnergyInfo = CsvProvider<"Sample.csv">

  let energyInfoBefore = EnergyInfo.Load("File1csv")
  let energyInfoAfter = EnergyInfo.Load("File2.csv")

  let expectedEnergyInfo =
    energyInfoBefore.Rows
      |> Seq.sortBy(fun r -> r.SomeProperty)
      |> Seq.map(fun r ->
        r.Property1,
        r.Property2,
        r.Property3,
        r.Property4,
        r.Property5,
        r.Property6,
        r.Property7)

  let actualEnergyInfo =
    energyInfoAfter.Rows
      |> Seq.sortBy(fun r -> r.SomeProperty)
      |> Seq.map(fun r ->
        r.Property1,
        r.Property2,
        r.Property3,
        r.Property4,
        r.Property5,
        r.Property6,
        r.Property7)
```

"expectedInfoBefore" and "expectedInfoAfter" are near identical and naturally I would like to have only one function.

So I thought I'd simply do:

```
  let getEnergyInfo energyInfo=
    energyInfo.Rows
      |> Seq.sortBy(fun r -> r.SomeProperty)
      |> Seq.map(fun r ->
        r.Property1,
        r.Property2,
        r.Property3,
        r.Property4,
        r.Property5,
        r.Property6,
        r.Property7)
```

However, at this point my code doesn't compile because the F# compiler is unable to infer the type.

[image]

However, I have no idea what type "energyInfo" is. When I hover over the latter, I'm told it's of type "CsvProvider<...>".

As I'm new to both F# and F# data I don't know what I have to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rows returned by your provider are of type `EnergyInfo.Row` (surprise!), and the whole file is of type `EnergyInfo`.

The compiler tells you that the type is `CsvProvider<"Sample.csv">`, because `EnergyInfo` is a type alias for `CsvProvider<"Sample.csv">`, and the compiler expands it in the error message. It probably could try to be a bit more helpful, but I'm not sure that's possible in general.

You can let the compiler know the right type by adding a type annotation:

```
let getEnergyInfo (energyInfo: EnergyInfo) =
    energyInfo.Rows
      |> Seq.sortBy(fun r -> r.SomeProperty)
      |> Seq.map(fun r ->
        r.Property1,
        r.Property2,
        r.Property3,
        r.Property4,
        r.Property5,
        r.Property6,
        r.Property7)
```